# Show action only on row hover in material-UI v5 data grid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using MUIv4 and built the following table component which show some actions on hover.

UI Before Hover
[image]

UI After Hover
[image]

Now I want to shift to MUI v5 Datagrid to replace this component. But could not find anything that could fulfill my design need i.e show actions on hover. Is there any way to do this on Datagrid component?

[Link of MUI5 DataGrid with somehow desire result](https://codesandbox.io/s/datagridprodemo-material-demo-forked-vghg7)

Note: I want to show the action on one row at a time like in gmail

Comment: please share the code with us... we need code to debug

Comment: I don't want to share the code. Firstly because its irrelevant and as I want to data grids from Material UI

Comment: At least try to create some sandbox with dummy data... for both versions... here: https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad added

Answer (score 1):

*Just give me the code*: https://codesandbox.io/s/datagridprodemo-material-demo-forked-63c9j?file=/demo.js:699-864

You can use `renderCell` with `Chip` like this:

```
renderCell: (params) => {
                return (
                  <Chip variant="outlined" size="small" label={params.value} />
                );
              }
```

As you are requiring some GMail like interface try setting the `icon` property of `Chip`. Reference: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v5.3.0/docs/src/pages/components/chips/IconChips.js

**And it looks something like this:**

[image: mui chip render like gmail]

Answer (score 0):

You could check this documentation about migration from v4 to v5 https://mui.com/components/data-grid/migration-v4/#removed-props.

There are some removed props related to hover event: `onCellEnter`, `onCellLeave`, `onRowEnter`, and `onRowLeave`. The developer said that they removed the props for better performance https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-x/issues/3799.

You could also check this documentation https://mui.com/components/data-grid/components/#row for the implementation examples when the mouse cursor enters or leaves the row or this documentation https://mui.com/components/data-grid/components/#cell when the mouse cursor enters or leaves the cell.